# how to append item to dictionary value is a list python

Tags: python

I have xlsx file like this

```
travel_df = pd.read_excel('../Data/TopMart.xlsx')
data = travel_df.to_dict('records')
```

the data look like this

```
parent_name_1      parent_name_2      parent_name_3
     A1                  B1                 C1
     A2                  B2                 C2
     A3                  B3                 C3
     A4                  B4                 C4
```

I want to make dict like this from that:

```
cat = {
    A1 : [B1, C1],
    A2 : [B2, C2],
    A3 : [B3, C3],
    A4 : [B4, C4],
}
```

what is the best way to do that

Comment: Do you need `A1: [B1, B1]` or `A1: [B1, C1]`?

Comment: @Marino my bad yes i need A1: [B1, C1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way, but you can try:

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xls = pandas.read_excel("test.xls")
    data = {xls.iloc[i][0]: list(xls.iloc[i][1:].values) for i in range(len(xls))}
```

Assuming that your first column has **unique** keys.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set **parent_name_1** as index.
2. Transpose the dataframe
3. Convert it to **dict** ignoring the new index after the transpose ***parent_1, parent_2, parent_3*** using **to_dict(orient="list")**.

`cat = travel_df.set_index("parent_name_1").T.to_dict(orient="list")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better function to do this directly, but I couldn't find it... But the `df.to_dict('split')` gets something that helps, and is easy enough to finish the way. This is what split gives us:

```
{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3],
 'columns': ['parent_name_1', 'parent_name_2', 'parent_name_3'],
 'data': [['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
  ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
  ['A3', 'B3', 'C3'],
  ['A4', 'B4', 'C4']]}
```

The `data` item here sort of has what we want, sort of...

```
l = df.to_dict('split')['data']
cat = dict()
for n in l:
    cat.update({n[0]:[n[1],n[2]]})
```

At the end of that, `cat` looks just how (I think) you want.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
    'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
    'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
})

result = my_data.set_index('A').to_dict('index')

{key: list(value.values()) for key, value in result.items()}
```

##### Result Object:

```
{'A1': {'B': 'B1', 'C': 'C1'},
 'A2': {'B': 'B2', 'C': 'C2'},
 'A3': {'B': 'B3', 'C': 'C3'},
 'A4': {'B': 'B4', 'C': 'C4'}}
```

##### Final Output

```
{'A1': ['B1', 'C1'],
 'A2': ['B2', 'C2'],
 'A3': ['B3', 'C3'],
 'A4': ['B4', 'C4']}
```